# How to arrange the items in QGridLayout as shown?

Tags: qt, qgridlayout

```
------------  ------
|          |  | 2  |
|          |  |    |
|     1    |  ------
|          |  ------  
|          |  |  3 |
------------  ------
```

How to arrange the `QGridLayout` like above?

I tried:

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
centralWidget->setLayout (layout);

layout->addWidget (objOne, 0, 0);
layout->addWidget (objTwo, 0, 1);
layout->addWidget (objThree, 1, 1);
```

but failed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check the [`addWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2) documentation. You can provide the `rowSpan` and `columnSpan`

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
centralWidget->setLayout (layout);

layout->addWidget (objOne, 0, 0, -1, 1);
layout->addWidget (objTwo, 0, 1, 1, 1);
layout->addWidget (objThree, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Notice however that it is much easier to create the desired layout using QtDesigner. Check [this `Qt` documentation page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) for more details

Answer (score 21):

Is it somehow mandatory for you to use QGridLayout for some reason? For simple layouts like this, I find it easier to use a combination of one QHBoxLayout and one QVBoxLayout.

```
QVBoxLayout* vlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
vlayout->addWidget(objTwo);
vlayout->addWidget(objThree);

QHBoxLayout* hlayout = new QHBoxLayout();
hlayout->addWidget(objOne);
hlayout->addLayout(vlayout);
```